# beans properties and modelDriven in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts 2. I created an action class that insert data from JSP page to a bean using `ModelDriven` interface.

The problem is that i have some non 'String`properties in the bean like`Long`,`Date` ... etc
The problem is:
when i press submit button in the jsp page i get an error saying that it did not find the a string setter for that particular property.
for example if i have in my bean

```
   package com.hsms.aseza.enteringApproval

   Class EnteringApproval

       private Date approvalDate

      Date getApprovalDate()
      {
         return employeeId;
      }

     void setApprovalDate(Date employeeId)
     {
         this.employeeId = employeeId;
     }
```

when the action class that implement the model driven is executed, it fires a run time exception

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  com.hsms.aseza.enteringApproval.EnteringApproval.setApprovalDate([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Is there anyway to solve this problem without writing a String setter for my `Date` property?

Comment: give the code of your  Action , Bean , JSP  you will get the answer. quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is conversion i.e. conversion from String to your `java.util.Date` Object. This [class](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/StrutsTypeConverter.html) extends [this](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/api/ognl/DefaultTypeConverter.html) which is responsible for converting from String to other types like Long, Double etc. If you check the source code for [DefaultTypeConverter](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/api/ognl/DefaultTypeConverter.html), you won't see any conversion for either `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`. So i think what you should do is to write a converter for `approvalDate`. My [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304255/how-to-get-foreign-keys-using-hibernate-annotations-struts-2-and-jsp/11308703#11308703) on this will guide you on the procedure, all you will need is to edit the code to suit your needs.

On your jsp, follow [this datepicker](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) example
Use the same format i.e date format used to display your date in your jsp with [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to do your conversion in `convertFromString` method of your converter and return the converted `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`.

Let me know if you have issues implementing this.

Comment: well, what you say is what i found yesterday, and to make think clearer, the implicit conversion fails if i have the day of month greater 12.

Comment: as you said the solution is to implement custom converter and i read how to do it, but as i read i have to make a converter for each class
the question now is how to make global converter, in other words i want a converter not only specific for this property "approvalDate",
i want a converter that convert to date using simple Date format where ever it finds a string to date conversion.

Comment: the problem why it fails if i put the days of month greater of 12 is that the implicit conversion that struts handles will convert based on my local system date format. in my local system the format is mm/dd/yyyy therefore as you said i need custom converter, but i need it global. i don't want to copy the converter in every place i need the conversion, why not to put in global place and every action that needs it will refer to it

Comment: @user1512999 It converts every instance of your date for the entire application. Once you configure `java.util.Date` in the `xwork-conversion.properties`, it will work for all your `java.util.Date` properties whether the property is in a `ModelDriven` bean or in the action class. You don't need to do it for every instance of `java.util.Date`. Moreso, follow the example that is in my post. i think that will be helpful. That way you won't need to do it for every instance. Hope this is clearer. Let me know if you have issues.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304255/how-to-get-foreign-keys-using-hibernate-annotations-struts-2-and-jsp/11308703#11308703 on how to use it.

Comment: thank you i will apply your solution and i will get back to you if i have any problems.
thank you again

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have initialized your bean in your action class

   ```
   Private YourBean bean = new YourBean();
   ```

   Or you can have it in the constructor
2. Make sure your getter and setter are public
3. If you are trying to type `date` on the jsp page, please use `datepicker` e.g. `sx:datetimepicker` or `sj:datepicker`

Comment: getter and setter are correct, and for the datepicker i'm using textfeild + JS calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the [`s:date`](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/date.html) tag in your jsp.

Edit:

Try use:

```
<s:textfield key="objEnteringApproval.approvalDate"></s:textfield>
```

in which objEnteringApproval is your public accessible variable in your controller.

Comment: hi, this should not be the problem, you can also use `s:property` to print date

Comment: @user1512999 use <s:textfield key="objEnteringApproval.approvalDate"></s:textfield>, in which objEnteringApproval is your public accessible variable in your controller.

Comment: s:date is for output, the problem happen when i map the date from jsp to action using ModelDriven