# datepicker submit string instead of date

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker, type-conversion, freemarker

In my web application, i am using struts2 and freemarker. Locale setting is in French `("dd/MM/yyyy")`.
In my freemarker template, i defined jQuery ui `datepicker` in an input element with name attribute that points to my object's date attribute.

The Problem is that, on form submit, SOMETIMES i'm getting `ognl` warning saying `"type conversion error - Cannot set String into the Date object."`. In response i can see message `cannot finc input results in my action.` It's quite strange because the problem occurs sometimes, sometimes not...

In my page, i have a list of products, with inputs and names like `product[1].startDate, product[2].startDate`, etc which are linked in my action by a List.

I tried setting `locale` into the `struts.properties` to French and this quite helps, but still in 10% of the time i can see this problem.

Can anyone tell me how to map a `datepicker` to a Date object without ognl converting it to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be due to `String` to `Date` conversion. Check two of my previous posts, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407265/beans-properties-and-modeldriven-in-struts-2/11408772#11408772) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304255/how-to-get-foreign-keys-using-hibernate-annotations-struts-2-and-jsp/11308703#11308703) for conversion details. You can also check the javadoc of [StrutsTypeConverter](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/StrutsTypeConverter.html) and [DefaultTypeConverter](http://www.opensymphony.com/ognl/api/ognl/DefaultTypeConverter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the dateFormat option when you call the `.datepicker()` function?

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy" });
```

Date picker allows you to select the format that's entered into the text field, and therefore passed on submission.