# Struts 2 type converter issue

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to use custom type conversion with property file for action.

Action class is implementing ModelDriven for bean properties.

```
public class WelcomeAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<MyBean>{

public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}

private MyBean bean = new MyBean();

@Override
public MyBean getModel() {
    return bean;
}
}
```

Bean class is:

```
public class MyBean{

private Rectangle rectangle;
public Rectangle getRectangle() {
    return rectangle;
}

public void setRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
    this.rectangle = rectangle;
}

}
```

and I have `WelcomeAction-conversion.properties` file parallel to action class with converter config as:

```
bean.rectangle=struts2.typeconverters.RectangleTypeConverter
```

I tried putting key as bean, rectangle etc but its not working, its not using converter class.

If i use `@TypeConverter` annotation or global converter then its working fine.

My struts 2 version is 2.3.15.1, any idea what could be the issue.

UPDATE: Created an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4249

Got the correct way for implementation: http://www.journaldev.com/2221/struts-2-ognl-tutorial-with-custom-type-converter-example

Comment: Have you tried this `rectangle=struts2.typeconverters.RectangleTypeConverter`?

Comment: yes I tried that too, its not working. I posted here only when I am out of options.

Comment: Not sure it is possible for model driven with conversion applied to action. You can apply converter to a bean or globally.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the same struts version. It is probably a bug with this Struts version.

Comment: @Pankaj: Because the model is on the top of the stack the conversion applied to action doesn't take effect. Not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Action class is using Model Driven then you need to follow this methodology for custom type convertor:

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html (see section titled Applying a Type Converter to a bean or model).

In your example I changed the conversion properties file name to MyJavaBean-conversion.properties and placed it under the same package as the MyJavaBean.java.

In MyJavaBean-conversion.properties I changed the key to:

```
      rectangle=com.journaldev.struts2.typeconverters.RectangleTypeConverter
```

I then built the .war file and ran your example under Tomcat 7.  The rectangle conversion worked correctly.

I don't think you could ever use the methodology explained at http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html (see section titled Applying a Type Converter to an Action) when your Action class is using ModelDriven. If you find a previous Struts 2 version where that did work let me know.

Bruce Phillips

Comment: Thanks Bruce, updated my article and project ZIP file at http://www.journaldev.com/2221/struts-2-ognl-tutorial-with-custom-type-converter-example

Comment: that answer is working for bean, but it is not for action class

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `xwork-conversion.properties` in your class path. In the file, you will map the full class name of `Rectangle` class to the `Converter` class. Follow the examples in the urls below.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407265/beans-properties-and-modeldriven-in-struts-2/11408772#11408772) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304255/how-to-get-foreign-keys-using-hibernate-annotations-struts-2-and-jsp/11308703#11308703) posts. They will help you in resolving the issues.

Comment: I know that it's working, please see my post snippet "If i use @TypeConverter annotation or global converter then its working fine.
"

Answer (score 0):

`bean.rectangle=struts2.typeconverters.RectangleTypeConverter` - This is wrong

You have to use the proper class names along with fullpath, not just property names.

`mypackage.Rectangle=struts2.typeconverters.RectangleTypeConverter` - hope you really have a package named struts2, although I'll strictly avoid such a package name.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with full class and converter name but even then it's not working, you were not telling me to do it on global level, right? regarding package name, its just to give example.

Comment: what do you mean by global level ?

Comment: global means for all the action classes in xwork-conversion.properties file.